# Is it better to delete non-usable indexes?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

The below query's result shows me the indexes statistics history. Is it better if I delete the indexes which return value of `0`  at `TotalNumberOfScan`?

```
SELECT
pt.tablename AS TableName
,t.indexname AS IndexName
,pc.reltuples AS TotalRows
,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(pt.tablename)::text)) AS TableSize
,pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(t.indexrelname)::text)) AS IndexSize
,t.idx_scan AS TotalNumberOfScan
,t.idx_tup_read AS TotalTupleRead
,t.idx_tup_fetch AS TotalTupleFetched
FROM pg_tables AS pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_class AS pc 
ON pt.tablename=pc.relname
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
SELECT 
    pc.relname AS TableName
    ,pc2.relname AS IndexName
    ,psai.idx_scan
    ,psai.idx_tup_read
    ,psai.idx_tup_fetch
    ,psai.indexrelname 
FROM pg_index AS pi
JOIN pg_class AS pc 
    ON pc.oid = pi.indrelid
JOIN pg_class AS pc2 
    ON pc2.oid = pi.indexrelid
JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes AS psai 
    ON pi.indexrelid = psai.indexrelid 
)AS T
ON pt.tablename = T.TableName
WHERE pt.schemaname='public'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my gold standard query to find all useless indexes:

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.relname AS tablename,
       s.indexrelname AS indexname,
       pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) AS index_size
FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_user_indexes s
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON s.indexrelid = i.indexrelid
WHERE s.idx_scan = 0      -- has never been scanned
  AND 0 <>ALL (i.indkey)  -- no index column is an expression
  AND NOT i.indisunique   -- is not a UNIQUE index
  AND NOT EXISTS          -- does not enforce a constraint
         (SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
          WHERE c.conindid = s.indexrelid)
ORDER BY pg_relation_size(s.indexrelid) DESC;
```

You need to consider that indexes have other uses than speeding up `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

- Many constraints are implemented by indexes, for example primary keys.
- Indexes on expressions make PostgreSQL collect statistics for the indexed expression, which can help the optimizer.

See [my blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/get-rid-of-your-unused-indexes/) for details.

Comment: Really this is great query, appreciate your great efforts but I need to ask you about the last column which is called "index_size" it gives the size in bytes or kilo bytes or what ?

Comment: This is in bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely you should remove indexes you're not using. Indexes speed up some operations, but at a cost - they need to be updated every time an insert, delete or some updates occur.

[Here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/update) is a great post about the cost of maintaining additional indexes on update, [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/delete) on delete and [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert) on insert. For example the time to insert into a table where there are 2 indexes is almost twice as long as for the same table with one index.